# In the Wordpress editor can I see the slugs instead of the title?

Tags: wordpress, menu

In the admin menu editor in the article box, i have many article with the same title, but different slug. it is very difficult to find the exact article.
there is a way to show the slug instead of the title in the box?

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkEjS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It should be automatically displayed beneath the title

[image]

You can also go to Screen Options and enable "slug" and it will appear in one of the boxes on the screen (the exact position depends on other settings, but generally it's lower on the page)

[image]

Comment: Ok but I'm talking about the menu not the article

Comment: Ah ok,  In that case use something like this:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-slug-column/